# How to get the whole bitmap attached to an ImageView?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I tried to get Bitmap attached to an ImageView, using `ImageView.getDrawingCache();` But I found that the returned Bitmap was not the same as I'd like to get from the ImageView. It was always smaller than the real image.

I had known that, the method `getDrawingCache()` should not have the view if it is bigger than the screen as the visible portion of the view is only drawn and the cache holds only what is drawn.

Could I get the whole bitmap attached to a ImageView?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you just want the `Bitmap` from a `ImageView` the following code may work for you:-

```
Bitmap bm=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

I think that's what you wanted.

Comment: I always get NPE: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()'.

Comment: sometimes the getDrawable might return someother object ..you might end with object cast exception.

Comment: @josher932 You might want to check mipreamble's answer for this. However I'd recommend you to check why are you getting a Null pointer, because it's not normal.

Comment: @Ravi It will obviously return a Drawable, but it may not be an object of BitmapDrawable class. Thus you'll need to check what kind of Drawable are you getting. mipremble's answer is much better in this respect.

Answer (score 14):

If your drawble is not always an instanceof BitmapDrawable

Note: ImageView should be set before you do this.

```
Bitmap bitmap;
if (mImageView.getDrawable() instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
} else {
    Drawable d = mImageView.getDrawable();
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    d.draw(canvas);
}
```

Your bitmap is stored in bitmap.

Voila!

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way is to set tag in `ImageView`.

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
imageView.setTag(bitmap);
```

To get Tag from it

```
imageView.getTag();
```