# Save the image from image view to another activity

Tags: android

I have a grid view, which contains a lot of images, when any image from the grid is tapped it comes in the center zoomed in, now i can keep swiping left or right with the help of a gesture. What i want is to introduce another gesture which saves the image which is zoomed at that instance be saved in another activity. How can i achieve this.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private GridView gv;
 private Animator mCurrentAnimator;
 private int mShortAnimationDuration;
 private int j = 0;

 private final GestureDetector detector = new GestureDetector(new SwipeGestureDetector());
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

 // Create Array thumbs resource id's:
 private int thumb[] = { R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two,
   R.drawable.three, R.drawable.four, R.drawable.five,
   R.drawable.six, R.drawable.seven,
   R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two, R.drawable.three,
   R.drawable.four, R.drawable.five, R.drawable.six,
   R.drawable.seven, R.drawable.eight,
   R.drawable.one };

 private ImageView expandedImageView;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  // Initialize the variables:
  gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

  // Set an Adapter to the ListView
  gv.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

  // Set on item click listener to the ListView
  gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
     long id) {

    // Display the zoomed in image in full screen
    j = pos;
    zoomImageFromThumb(v, thumb[pos]);

   }
  });

  // Set the Animation time form the android defaults
  mShortAnimationDuration = getResources().getInteger(
    android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

 }

 // Create an Adapter Class extending the BaseAdapter
 class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

  public ImageAdapter(MainActivity activity) {
   // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
   // Set the count value to the total number of items in the Array
   return thumb.length;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return position;
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return position;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   // Inflate the item layout and set the views
   View listItem = convertView;
   int pos = position;
   if (listItem == null) {
    listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
   }

   // Initialize the views in the layout
   ImageView iv = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.thumb);

   // Set the views in the layout
   iv.setBackgroundResource(thumb[pos]);

   return listItem;
  }

 }



 private void zoomImageFromThumb(final View thumbView, int imageResId) {
  // If there's an animation in progress, cancel it immediately and
  // proceed with this one.
  if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
   mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
  }

  // Load the high-resolution "zoomed-in" image.
  expandedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.expanded_image);

  expandedImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (detector.onTouchEvent(event))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        });

  expandedImageView.setImageResource(imageResId);

  // Calculate the starting and ending bounds for the zoomed-in image.
  // This step
  // involves lots of math. Yay, math.
  final Rect startBounds = new Rect();
  final Rect finalBounds = new Rect();
  final Point globalOffset = new Point();

  // The start bounds are the global visible rectangle of the thumbnail,
  // and the
  // final bounds are the global visible rectangle of the container view.
  // Also
  // set the container view's offset as the origin for the bounds, since
  // that's
  // the origin for the positioning animation properties (X, Y).
  thumbView.getGlobalVisibleRect(startBounds);
  findViewById(R.id.container).getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds,
    globalOffset);
  startBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);
  finalBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);

  // Adjust the start bounds to be the same aspect ratio as the final
  // bounds using the
  // "center crop" technique. This prevents undesirable stretching during
  // the animation.
  // Also calculate the start scaling factor (the end scaling factor is
  // always 1.0).
  float startScale;
  if ((float) finalBounds.width() / finalBounds.height() > (float) startBounds
    .width() / startBounds.height()) {
   // Extend start bounds horizontally
   startScale = (float) startBounds.height() / finalBounds.height();
   float startWidth = startScale * finalBounds.width();
   float deltaWidth = (startWidth - startBounds.width()) / 2;
   startBounds.left -= deltaWidth;
   startBounds.right += deltaWidth;
  } else {
   // Extend start bounds vertically
   startScale = (float) startBounds.width() / finalBounds.width();
   float startHeight = startScale * finalBounds.height();
   float deltaHeight = (startHeight - startBounds.height()) / 2;
   startBounds.top -= deltaHeight;
   startBounds.bottom += deltaHeight;
  }

  // Hide the thumbnail and show the zoomed-in view. When the animation
  // begins,
  // it will position the zoomed-in view in the place of the thumbnail.
  thumbView.setAlpha(0f);
  expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

  // Set the pivot point for SCALE_X and SCALE_Y transformations to the
  // top-left corner of
  // the zoomed-in view (the default is the center of the view).
  expandedImageView.setPivotX(0f);
  expandedImageView.setPivotY(0f);

  // Construct and run the parallel animation of the four translation and
  // scale properties
  // (X, Y, SCALE_X, and SCALE_Y).
  AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
  set.play(
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X,
      startBounds.left, finalBounds.left))
    .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y,
      startBounds.top, finalBounds.top))
    .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X,
      startScale, 1f))
    .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_Y,
      startScale, 1f));
  set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
  set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
  set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
   @Override
   public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
    mCurrentAnimator = null;
   }

   @Override
   public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
    mCurrentAnimator = null;
   }
  });
  set.start();
  mCurrentAnimator = set;

  // Upon clicking the zoomed-in image, it should zoom back down to the
  // original bounds
  // and show the thumbnail instead of the expanded image.
  final float startScaleFinal = startScale;
  expandedImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
    if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
     mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
    }

    // Animate the four positioning/sizing properties in parallel,
    // back to their
    // original values.
    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set.play(
      ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X,
        startBounds.left))
      .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y,
        startBounds.top))
      .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView,
        View.SCALE_X, startScaleFinal))
      .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView,
        View.SCALE_Y, startScaleFinal));
    set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
    set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
     @Override
     public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
      thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
      expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      mCurrentAnimator = null;
     }

     @Override
     public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
      thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
      expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      mCurrentAnimator = null;
     }
    });
    set.start();
    mCurrentAnimator = set;
   }
  });
 }


 private class SwipeGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            try {
                if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                   if(thumb.length>j)
                    {
                        j++;

                        if(j < thumb.length)
                        {                           
                         expandedImageView.setImageResource(thumb[j]);
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            j = 0;
                            expandedImageView.setImageResource(thumb[j]);
                            return true;
                        }

                    }
                }
                else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {


                    if(j>0)
                    {
                        j--;
                        expandedImageView.setImageResource(thumb[j]);
                        return true;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                     j = thumb.length-1;
                     expandedImageView.setImageResource(thumb[j]);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return false;
        }
    }

}
```

I hope somebody finds a solution for me because it has taken a lot of time and i am failing after all my attempts. Thank-you.

My TRY

```
    private class SwipeGestureDetector extends
            GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
            try {
                if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                    if (thumb.length > j) {
                        j++;

                        if (j < thumb.length) {
                            expandedImageView.setImageResource(thumb[j]);
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            j = 0;
                            expandedImageView.setImageResource(thumb[j]);
                            return true;
                        }

                    }
                } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                    if (j > 0) {
                        j--;
                        expandedImageView.setImageResource(thumb[j]);
                        return true;

                    } else {
                        j = thumb.length - 1;
                        expandedImageView.setImageResource(thumb[j]);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

        Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable) expandedImageView.getDrawable())
                .getBitmap();
    }

    private void storeImage(Bitmap bm) {
        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
        String TAG = null;
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");// e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private File getOutputMediaFile() {
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/"
                        + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/Files");

        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm")
                .format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        String mImageName = "MI_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + mImageName);
        return mediaFile;
    }

}
```

I have managed to complete it till here, could anyone please highlight my mistakes and guide me a little bit more?

Comment: what is your problem - getting/saving the current zoom level or displaying the image in some other `Activity`? Your question is a bit unclear

Comment: @Droidman It is a grid view actually, but when any image from the grid is clicked, it comes to the front center as it is supposed to be. No problem till here i am just explaining the mechanism of the app. Now when any image is selected from the grid i want to perform a gesture so that the selected image at that instance gets saved to another activity. That is it what i want..

Comment: get the `Bitmap` from `ImageView` using `getDrawingCache()`, write it into a tmp file on SD card, then pass its path to another `Activity` via an `Intent`?

Comment: @Droidman oh man, could you please refer me some example or a tutorial?

Comment: [get the Bitmap from ImageView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741749/how-to-get-the-whole-bitmap-attached-to-an-imageview) then  [save it to some location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662258/how-to-save-a-bitmap-on-internal-storage) then [pass its location to another Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707900/pass-a-string-from-one-activity-to-another-activity-in-android) and then [read it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181774/show-image-view-from-file-path-in-android)

Comment: @Droidman i tried and followed all the steps, but having alot of few small errors, could you plzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz edit my code for that matter, i would be so so thank full to you, it has taken up my days and i fail everyday,

Comment: I need to see your error logs to be able to help